# How to put session variable in value=""

Tags: php, session-variables

I tried this but it is not working:

```
 $email = $_SESSION['email'];

    <input class="form-control" type="text" name='email' value='<?php echo $email; ?>'>
```

Is it even possible to do that and if it is how?

Comment: Really? You just did it!! How is this even a question?

Comment: session not started, variables don't get parsed in single quotes; *so there*. Need I say more?

Comment: *"Is it even possible to do that and if it is how?"* Yes it is possible. ^^^ See that ^^^

Comment: _variables don't get parsed in single quotes_ - while that is true, it's not applicable here because he's not doing string interpolation.

Comment: I don't know how to be more clear - in this specific case, the single quotes are not relevant. The value of `$email` will be output.

Comment: well @SeanBright there's something I am definitely not grasping here. Unless you meant `value='<?php echo $email; ?>'` will be `$email`. as a code represenation of what you said up there.

Comment: It's hard to tell since we can't the first line is PHP, and the second line *might* be HTML and not in PHP brackets. But there isn't enough code to tell us that.

Comment: @SeanBright *Facepalm* - lol Ok, I deserved that hahaha. Gawd, I was sure that the single quotes were an issue here. You may now swift kick me in the *you know what* now lol and/or cross-side the head

Comment: so the almighty answer here is, yes... only if you started the session. Otherwise, what you posted........... won't work.

Comment: *SwaaaaaaaBANG Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Yeah, I deserved that one Sam!* @JayBlanchard major duh on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posted will work, but **only** if you started the session.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['email'] = "email@example.com";

 $email = $_SESSION['email'];

?>

<input class="form-control" type="text" name='email' value='<?php echo $email; ?>'>
```

Which will place email@example.com in the input.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

and being corrected by Sean, in regards to string interpolation; that was my mistake.

If you want to use that input in a form, be sure to use form tags if using pure PHP.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: @TolgaKantarov actually Tolga, you weren't stupid; I was lol and Sean quickly corrected me on that. One never ceases to learn and I for one, have learned something today, including a "lesson" ;-) *Cheers*